# C++ ignores if statement conditions

Tags: c++, if-statement

So I'm writing this code simply for practice, and I'm having an issue where I have several if statements in a row, but even if the user input does not satisfy any of the first if statement's conditions, it prints the data from the first if statement. The part that I'm having trouble with is at the bottom of the code, right above the "return 0" part.

```
// ConsoleApplication4.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <istream>

using namespace std;

class all_supp{
    private:
        string name, type;
    public:
        all_supp();
        all_supp(string y);

        void enterType(string x);
        string getType();

        void enterName(string y);
        string getName();
};

//Define Variables
all_supp::all_supp()
{
    name = "unknown";
    type = "unknown";
}

all_supp::all_supp(string y)
{
    name = y;
    type = "unknown";
}

void all_supp::enterType(string x)
{
    type = x;
}

string all_supp::getType()
{
    return type;
}

void all_supp::enterName(string y)
{
    name = y;
}

string all_supp::getName()
{
    return name;
}



// MusclePharm Assault structure
struct preworkout_assault{
    static int creatine_hcl, creatine_mono;
    static double cost;
};

int preworkout_assault::creatine_hcl = 250;
int preworkout_assault::creatine_mono = 1000;
double preworkout_assault::cost = 29.99;

// C4 Extreme structure
struct preworkout_c4{
    static int creatine_hcl, creatine_mono, creatine_nitrate, caffeine;
    static double cost;
};

int preworkout_c4::creatine_hcl = 0;
int preworkout_c4::creatine_mono = 0;
int preworkout_c4::caffeine = 135;
int preworkout_c4::creatine_nitrate = 1000;
double preworkout_c4::cost = 29.99;

// BSN N.).-Xplode structure
struct preworkout_bsn{
    static int creatine_hcl, creatine_mono, creatine_nitrate, caffeine;
    static double cost;
};

int preworkout_bsn::creatine_hcl = 0;
int preworkout_bsn::creatine_mono = 0;
int preworkout_bsn::caffeine = 135;
int preworkout_bsn::creatine_nitrate = 1000;
double preworkout_bsn::cost = 29.99;

// How the structures are accessed within main
preworkout_assault assault_data;
preworkout_c4 c4_data;
preworkout_bsn bsn_data;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    //Access general class
    all_supp all;

    //Variables
    string set_type, set_name;

    cout << "Welcome to the bodybuilding supplement recommendation application!" << endl << endl;
    cout << "The categories of supplements that this application includes are:" << endl << "- Pre-workouts" << endl << "- Intra-workouts" << endl << "- Fat-loss boosters" << endl << "- Recovery boosters" << endl << endl;
    cout << "White kind of supplement are you looking for? ";
    
    // Choose the type of supplement
    cin >> set_type;

    all.enterType(set_type);

        if(getline(cin,set_type) == "pre-workout" || "preworkout" || "pre workout" || "preworkouts" || "pre-workouts" || "pre workouts")
        {
            cout << "Okay, so you're looking for a pre-workout!" << endl;
            cout << "These are the top five pre-workout products currently on the market:" << endl << endl;
            cout << "- MusclePharm Assault\n- Cellucor C4 Extreme\n- BSN N.O.-Xplode 2.0\n- Pro Supps MR. HYDE\n- Driven Sports CRAZE" << endl << endl;
            cout << "Which of the listed pre-workouts would you like to learn more about? Type \"exit\"if you would like to switch the type of supplement you are looking for.";
        
            cin >> set_name;

            all.enterName(set_name);

            if(all.getName() == "musclepharm assault", "assault", "musclepharm", "muscle", "pharm", "assaullt", "asault")
            {
                //Print MusclePharm Assault data from struct here
                cout << endl << endl << "Awesome! Here's some information about MusclePharm Assault:" << endl << "- Cost per 30 servings: $" << assault_data.cost << endl << "- Creatine monohydrate content per serving: " << assault_data.creatine_mono << "mg" << endl << "- Creatine HCl per serving: " << assault_data.creatine_hcl << "mg" << endl;
            }

            else if(all.getName() == "Cellucor C4 Extreme", "cellucor", "c4", "extreme", "c", "4")
            {
                //Print C4 data from struct here
                cout << endl << endl << "Awesome! Here's some information about Cellucor C4 Extreme:" << endl << "- Cost per 30 servings: $" << c4_data.cost << endl << "- Creatine monohydrate content per serving: " << c4_data.creatine_mono << "mg" << endl << "- Creatine HCl per serving: " << c4_data.creatine_hcl << "mg" << endl << "- Creatine Nitrate per serving: " << c4_data.creatine_nitrate << "mg" << endl << "- Caffeine per serving: " << c4_data.caffeine << endl << endl;
            }

            else if(all.getName() == "BSN N.O.-Xplode 2.0", "bsn", "no", "bsn no", "n.o.", "n.o")
            {
                //Print C4 data from struct here
                cout << endl << endl << "Awesome! Here's some information about BSN N.O.-Xplode 2.0:" << endl << "- Cost per 30 servings: $" << bsn_data.cost << endl << "- Creatine monohydrate content per serving: " << bsn_data.creatine_mono << "mg" << endl << "- Creatine HCl per serving: " << bsn_data.creatine_hcl << "mg" << endl << "- Creatine Nitrate per serving: " << bsn_data.creatine_nitrate << "mg" << endl << "- Caffeine per serving: " << bsn_data.caffeine << endl << endl;
            }
        }

    cout << endl << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In C and C++, the || operator is a binary operator. And non-zero values are true.

Your expression:

```
   getline(cin,set_type) == "pre-workout" || "preworkout" || "pre workout" || "preworkouts" || "pre-workouts" || "pre workouts")
```

first tests whether the istream returned by getline() is equal to a string. It's not. Then it
tests the next expression, "preworkout" -- a literal string whose value is a non-zero integral address, which is considered true. Consequently, the body of the if statement is executed.

Try this instead:

```
 getline(cin,set_type);
 if( set_type == "pre-workout" 
     || set_type == "preworkout" 
     || set_type == "pre workout" 
     || set_type == "preworkouts" 
     || set_type == "pre-workouts" 
     || set_type == "pre workouts")
```

Comment: So when I do this, I will enter "pre-workout" or any of the other names that I allowed, but it goes straight to "return 0". When I get rid of "getline(cin,set_type);" I no longer have the error. Although I'm glad you pointed out this problem (I didn't notice it at first), my main issues were the "if" statements below the one that you pointed out. For some reason the only information I can get the console to return is that of the first "if" statement (being the MusclePharm Assault data). Could you help me with that?

Comment: It looks like you try to get the set_type twice, once with "cin >> set_type" and then again with getline(). The second one is probably giving you an empty string, which isn't equal to any non-empty string. Also, note that your embedded if's appear to be trying to use the comma operator to mean OR. It's a valid operator, but it doesn't do that. Use a similar fix to the one I showed above. [The value of an expression with commas is the value of the last expression.]

Answer (score 1):

Lots of issues.

`getline` returns stream and not your input string.  So, you will need a statement like

```
getline(cin,set_type);
```

that should get your input in `set_type`.  Then, your `if` statement will be:

```
if ( set_type == "pre-workout" || set_type == "preworkout" || set_type == "pre workout" || set_type == "preworkouts" || set_type == "pre-workouts" || set_type == "pre workouts")
```

Comment: Okay this works, however what if I wanted to change the "getline" to "all.getType()"? When I tried that previously, only single words such as "preworkout" etc. would work, nothing with spaces such as          "pre workout". How would you recommend fixing this?

Comment: You will have to parse the input yourself to account for that.  `getline` will get you a string with spaces but if your want to grab a substring (containing spaces) from there, you will have to code that yourself.

Comment: Okay thank you. Also, the "getline(cin,set_type);" makes the program skip straight to return 0. When I remove that line, it runs fine... is that okay?

Comment: You can try to see what is input by using `cout << set_type << endl;` and make sure that you get the correct input.

Comment: And your other `if` statements also need to be fixed.  `,` is a valid operator in C++ and that is why you are not getting error messages.